# Why has "as it did" been used in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> Coming as it did just after the success of The Shape of Water at the Oscars, the book became an instant bestseller.

I don't know what difference would it have made had I not used "as it did" after "coming".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can omit the "as it did" part making it

> Coming just after the success of The Shape of Water at the Oscars, the book became an instant bestseller.

However, the "as it did" puts emphasis on the final state of the book that was released. It gives rise to the possibility, that if the book had been written in another way (and not as it was ;) ) it might not have been an instant bestseller.